# What is a great way to find some freelance talent offline?

Tags: outsourcing

There are several websites like `Upwork` and `Fiverr` is that all of the freelance is usually goods that can be done digitally (e.g. Photoshop, Voiceover, Web Design, Graphics Design, and etc).

But there are also some freelance work that I will need some people to come to the venue to do the work. (e.g. Photography, Livestreaming, and etc.)

I am already posting several advertisements on local Facebook groups trying to find people that can come to our area to help take product photography shots, as well as livestream for our online store. But it has been a week or so and I am not even close to finding the perfect candidate.

I have went to a `Youtube crawler` and watching low subscriber count Youtubers and watching their content 1 by 1 and messaging their e-mail if they are interested. But it is very tedious and still have not had any success.

I am struggling growing my business because as an entrepreneur and growing business I cannot handle doing everything by myself. But at the same time finding talent is difficult.

What is the fastest and best way to find skilled freelancers that can come to your venue?

Comment: How does one find **any** worker locally? Ads, temp agencies, etc.

Comment: @Scott right but I am wondering what are some good methods to actually scout for some talent that is useful for some small entrepreneurs like me. I have a growing business but I need to find talent that is not too expensive to help me grow my business as I have come to a point where work is overload. Some methods like Ads are too big of a scale and cost inefficient on many cases as well as agencies. Finding photographers are a challenge, but I was thinking of going to an arts school locally and actually have a flier or something to catch students who are able and want some freelance side job

Answer (score 1):

Find a local makerspace and make friends there. They are usually a magnet for creative types. These people usually have a wide background of experience and often don't do their work specialty at the makerspace, so just judging people by their habits there isn't very accurate.

Makerspaces (aka: hackerspace, Fablab) are found all over the US in almost all major cities, most large cities, and quite a few smaller towns. These are usually places that have woodworking, metal working, 3D printers, laser cutters, pottery kilns, electronics, programming, and more. Not all of them have the same stuff or even the stuff I just listed, but they all have the same basic idea behind them: creative people doing work. Usually it's either fun work as a hobby or home improvement work they don't have the tools for themselves, but there's also usually at least a handful that are trying to replace or supplement their day job. And any of this whole group of people are likely to be interested in doing a side project for a friend or for some side money.

However, don't expect to go there to "rent-a-person". Too often people come in and think they can hire the place to do manufacturing for them, or design a product off specs, or act like a temp agency. No, go there to make friends, learn about the space, learn about people and their abilities, and then approach individuals to see if they are interested in a project. Most times, the makerspace is a member run organization of volunteers. Very few have employees, except for the for-profit commercial versions. They are more of a community or group of makers that share tools, knowledge, and experience rather than a manufacturing company.

BTW, makerspaces can also be found all over the world, too. Many industrial countries are similar to the US in how easily they can be found, but can be harder to find, if they even exist, in less developed countries. Less developed countries would probably benefit most from these types of place, but I digress.

Here's one map that might help you find a location near you. (I'm not affiliated with this site, it's just the first one I could find.)

> https://www.beautyandthebolt.com/makerspace-map

FYI, I've been a part of 2 makerspace, and am currently a member of one. I do everything I mentioned above about makerspaces (and more), but I also so software development and have done computer repair in the past for work. I've met mechanical, network, chemical, and electrical engineers, photographers, painters, graphic artists, inventors, business owners, and a whole lot more at makerspaces. I've also gone to functions to promote the makerspace that included business people, investors, community leaders, and other DIY type people. This type of networking can be indispensable when looking for people to help your business.

Getting into the business of running the makerspace can be frustrating, and I'd suggest trying to stay out of it, but that's off the target for this Answer.